# Getting a pre-populated database into an android app

Tags: android, database, android-studio, android-room

Currently, I have a database called "data_eng.db" in my C: drive. It contains a bunch of quiz questions and other information about them on my quiz app. I created it with "DB Browser for SQLite".

I now want to get this prepopulated database from my computer that I created it on, to always be packaged with the android app in the /data/data/com.example/database/ folder when I run it from Android Studio

I understand that I need to use Room.databaseBuilder and put the path of my database (path of the db from the android device) in either the creatFromAsset or create from file parameter. However, I don't know how to get my database that's on my computer to an emulator or my phone without just copying the file over.

Edit 1 (Addressing comment concerns) :

Here is the code where I build a Room database based on a prepopulated database in the assets folder of my apk on the android device.

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.example.infinityquiz.model.Question

@Database(entities = [Question::class], version = 2, exportSchema = false)
abstract class QuestionDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun questionDao(): QuestionDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: QuestionDatabase? = null
        private const val PATH = "database/data_eng.db"
        private const val NAME = "multiple_choice_questions"

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(context, QuestionDatabase::class.java, "data_eng.db").createFromAsset(PATH).build()


        fun getDatabase(context: Context): QuestionDatabase{
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if(tempInstance != null){
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this){
                val instance = buildDatabase(context)
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my entity class as well:

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "multiple_choice_questions")//, foreignKeys=[], indices=[])
data class Question (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val Question: String,
    val Category: String,
    val Subcategory: String,
    val AnswerOne: String,
    val AnswerTwo: String,
    val AnswerThree: String,
    val AnswerFour: String,
    val CorrectAnswer: Int,
    val WasQuestionSeen: Int,
    val Wikipedia: String
): Parcelable
```

The database I created has a format similar to the one posted below, so I believe the schemas of the Room and the SQLite database are inline.
Here is the CREATE command for the table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE "multiple_choice_questions" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "Question"  TEXT,
    "Category"  TEXT,
    "Subcategory"   TEXT,
    "AnswerOne" TEXT,
    "AnswerTwo" TEXT,
    "AnswerThree"   TEXT,
    "AnswerFour"    TEXT,
    "CorrectAnswer" INTEGER,
    "WasQuestionSeen"   INTEGER,
    "Wikipedia" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

[And here is a screenshot of a sample couple lines from the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY3QI.png)

Comment: "I've tried creating an assets folder in Android Studio but when I put the db in there, it never installs when I run the app." -- your [mcve] should show your code where you are using `createFromAsset()`. "I have a database called "data_eng.db"" -- how did you create it? How are you ensuring that the database schema matches what Room needs for your entity classes?

Comment: @CommonsWare I hoped to address some concerns you made in the current edit. I hope the code shown now will help answer the question. To be honest, I haven't worked much with databases, some I'm still a bit unsure when it comes to schemas. I'm just trying to have the database I created on my computer(with SQLite) to be able to be in the app's assets folder on whatever emulator I run it on, so it can be read by the Room database.

Comment: "I believe the schemas of the Room and the SQLite database are inline" -- they look compatible, but you really should use the schemas that Room gives you to be certain. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#export-schema) to get Room to export those in JSON where you can see them. Beyond that, make sure that your database is in the proper spot in the project. For a module named `app`, it would be `app/src/main/assets/database/data_eng.db`. Also, clear data or uninstall/reinstall, as Room only uses the asset if there is no database.